# wicket PageParameters encoding

Tags: java, wicket

My project is under eclipse, Tomcat, Spring, Hibernate. In my web app when I try go to enother webPage :

```
public void onSubmit()
        {                                   
            String value="Д";
            PageParameters pars=new PageParameters();
            pars.add("strname", value);
            setResponsePage(FilterClient.class, pars);
        }
```

and after geting that parameter :

```
public FilterClient(final PageParameters parameters) {
        String strName="";
        if(parameters.containsKey("strname")){
            strName=parameters.getString("strname");
        }
```

the value of parameter is

```
Ð” instead of Д
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I have tried using URIEncoding="UTF-8" in the connector tag of my 
tomcat server.xml ? 

something like following: 

<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
            maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
            enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
URIEncoding="UTF-8"/> 

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Wicket-tomcat-and-UTF-8-td1870582.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to set URIEncoding in Tomcat server.xml configuration file.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Best practice is use only UTF-8 encoding in your application (in database and web-pages).

Comment: Thank's Leonid. I have added URIEncoding="UTF-8" in the connector tag of my tomcat server.xml and it's worked.

Answer (score 2):

what encoding do you use?

You should try using UTF-8.

Try writing following in your templates at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Wicket determines per default the output encoding based on that.

There is a little information about it in the javadoc:

http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Page.html#configureResponse%28%29